# source file (.ts) not showing up in the dev tool after deployment

Tags: angular, typescript, google-chrome-devtools, package.json, angular.json

I am only able to see the .ts source file in my local but after I deploy it, I cannot see them in any environment. I already have my sourcemap set to true and have also set my browserTarget under serve. It is still not working. Please help!

Here is my angular.json file

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "UI-App": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": ["zone.js"],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"],
            "styles": [
              "@fabric/components/legacy-theme.css",
              "@fabric/components/theme.css",
              "@fabric/primeng-styles/light-theme.css",
              "./node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
              "./node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
              "./node_modules/primeflex/primeflex.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "allowedCommonJsDependencies": ["color"]
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "optimization": {
                "scripts": true,
                "styles": true,
                "fonts": false
              },
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "ui-angular-demo:build",
            "host": "localhost.gm.com",
            "ssl": true,
            "port": 8081
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "UI-App:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "UI-App:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "UI-App:build"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-eslint/builder:lint",
          "options": {
            "lintFilePatterns": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.html"]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "schematicCollections": ["@angular-eslint/schematics"]
  },
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "style": "scss",
      "standalone": true
    },
    "@schematics/angular:directive": {
      "standalone": true
    },
    "@schematics/angular:pipe": {
      "standalone": true
    },
    "@schematics/angular:application": {
      "strict": true
    },
    "@angular-eslint/schematics:application": {
      "setParserOptionsProject": true
    },
    "@angular-eslint/schematics:library": {
      "setParserOptionsProject": true
    }
  }
}
```

And here is the snippet of my package.json

```
"name": "UI-App",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "lint:fix": "ng lint --fix",
    "format": "prettier --write src",
    "format:check": "prettier --check src",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "clean": "node scripts/clean.mjs"
  },
```

This is my devtool in my local. I am able to see the src folder.[image]
This is my devtool after i deployed my app. Not able to see the src folder. So, when I do Ctrl+P I cannot select any files.[image]
This is my dev tool for a different app that is displying the folder structure after deploying my app to the Dev environment. I need to be able see this folder structure after deploying it to any environment for debugging purpose. But Currently I only see the folder structure when I am working in my local.
[image]

Comment: When you build your angular project it converts .ts into .js files. Unless, I didn't understand your question correctly...

Comment: I just added some screenshots to show what I mean.  I do not see the src folder  in my devtool in chrome when I inspect my app. I can see it in my local but it would not show up when after i deploy  the app.

Comment: first of all, after you built Angular it converts all t.s into .js and not using .ts to run the website. When you run ```ng serve``` locally, it builds the application and start watching for changes in src folder. If any file is changed it will re-build the application automatically and as result you will have new .js files. Not sure why are you looking to have .ts files in your deploy package?

Comment: I have set the "sorucemap: true" so it should map all the compiled JS files  to TS. I have added one more screenshot to share what the devtool for one of my working deployed app behaves. i can see the while folder structure so its easy to see what are all the code base that has been deployed to that particular environment. But its not working for my other app. So cant see the code base for already deployed app.

Answer (score 0):

Source map files allow dev tools to "convert" the JS files back to TS.

They're not really readable on their own.

If you wish to obtain the same result as your local environment when you build, then you should run

```bash
npx ng serve -c development
```

This will use the development environment, which is the one configured to keep the source files in your config.

To be noted, it is advised not to do that for a production build.